# use caffe to train Lenet with CSV data

Tags: python, caffe, kaggle

Excuse me, I have a question on using caffe for hd data? I try to run an example on the Kaggle mnist csv data with the  following steps

1. use `h5py` to convert it to h5 data. (I use the caffe-example.py to convert)
2. Then modify the lenet_train_test_prototxt and train it. I am quite at a loss of this step.

The only change I made here is

```
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "data/mnist_train_h5.txt"
    batch_size: 64
  }
}
```

how to change the lenet_train_test_prototxt to suit the data? Or also there are some other files I need to change? The error log is

```
enF0724 18:21:11.052737 79373 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:76] Check failed: !this->layer_param_.has_transform_param() HDF5Data does not transform data.

> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>     @     0x7fe8188bbdaa  (unknown)
>     @     0x7fe8188bbce4  (unknown)
>     @     0x7fe8188bb6e6  (unknown)
>     @     0x7fe8188be687  (unknown)
>     @     0x7fe818caec10  caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
>     @     0x7fe818c520a3  caffe::Net<>::Init()
>     @     0x7fe818c53e12  caffe::Net<>::Net()
>     @     0x7fe818c0ba20  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
>     @     0x7fe818c0c9c3  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
>     @     0x7fe818c0cb96  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
>     @           0x40c8f0  caffe::GetSolver<>()
>     @           0x406541  train()
>     @           0x404a81  main
>     @     0x7fe817dcdec5  (unknown)
>     @           0x40502d  (unknown)
>     @              (nil)  (unknown) Aborted (core dumped)ter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have one hdf5 data file `'data/mnist_train_h5.hd5'`.

1. As you can see from the error message you got, `"HDF5Data"` layer does not support data transformation. Specifically, you cannot scale the data by the layer.
   Thus, any transformations you wish to have, you must apply them *yourself* during the creation of `'data/mnist_train_h5.hd5'`.
2. `"HDF5Data"` layer does not accept `data_param`, but rather `hdf5_data_param` with a parameter `source` specifying a *list* of hd5 binary files. In your case you should prepare an extra *text* file `'data/mnist_train_h5.txt'` with a single line:

> data/mnist_train_h5.hd5

This text file will tell caffe to read `'data/mnist_train_h5.hd5'`.

The resulting layer should look like:

```
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "data/mnist_train_h5.txt"
    batch_size: 64
  }
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one question regarding data transformation.  Here is my code: [http://luoyetx.me/2015/04/little-caffe/]. Please see his first piece of code here (too long to paste here). I am not sure what additional data transformation I need to do besides that piece of code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you mean `source: "mnist_train_h5.txt"` instead of `source: "data/mnist_train_h5.hd5"`  ?

Comment: @mrgloom thanks for spotting this bug! - corrected it just now.