# Using Neural Networks for Data Manipulation

Tags: neural-network, caffe, torch, conv-neural-network

Perhaps related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112941/multiple-category-classification-in-caffe), but my goal is to have a network perform a manipulation on an input image and output the resulting image data.

In the event this question lacks clarity, I would be glad to delve into deeper detail of my problem in the comments. However, I'll try to be as non-case-specific as possible, to make this question of use to others.

### The Problem

I have a plethora of training data consisting of images before and after the proposed manipulation. My question relates to how I can train 1-to-1 each pixel using Caffe. My loss should take the form of something that computes the difference between the two images.

If I have my last fully-connected/inner-product layer outputting `channels * height * width` and I have my label of the expected output image (same dimensions) what type of loss+accuracy structure should I use?

### My Case

I've tried simply passing the inner-product data to a sigmoid cross-entropy loss with my label data, but it doesn't seem to be a supported method.

My labels are non integer values, as they are pixel RGB data between 0 and 1 (**Note:** I could use integers in the form of 0 to 255) and Caffe seems to interpret labels as categories as opposed to simple values.

I could have 255 categories per pixel channel, but that would result in 255 * 3 channels * 256 height * 256 width = 50,135,040 categories, which is absurdly over complicating what I'm trying to achieve.

### My Questions

- Does Caffe natively support what I'm trying to achieve?

  - If so, how should I change my structure to conform to these specification?
  - If not, do any other neural network frameworks such as Torch support this?
- Is there a name for the type of problem I'm trying to solve with my network (certainly not categorical classification)?

  - What has been used in the past to solve this style of problem?

### Sources With Potential Value

- [Training Super-Resolution Image Upscaling](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kahe/publications/eccv14srcnn.pdf)
- [Karol Gregor on Variational Autoencoders and Image Generation](https://youtu.be/P78QYjWh5sM) (less relevant as this touches on model reconstruction)

Comment: cross entropy is for **classification**, while your problem is (multivariate) **regression**, use the loss function which is defined for this kind of problem (such as mean squared error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loss layer you are looking for is [Euclidean loss layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1EuclideanLossLayer.html) (Mean Squared Error):

```
layers {
  name: "loss"
  type: EUCLIDEAN_LOSS
  top: "loss"
  bottom: "CONVX_15"
  bottom: "labels"
}
```

Your problem is multivariate regression and you have to use loss which is suitable for it. **Sigmoid cross-entropy loss** is for classification, where the target values (labels) have to be between 0 and 1 (e.g. probability that a pixel is on/off).

With euclidean loss, be carefull to manage your gradients. Keep your target values in range <0,1> and use Xavier weight initialization. Still, you will probably need to set lower learning rate compared to classification problems to keep the SGD from exploding.