# Accuracy issue in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a network which has 4 Boolean outputs. It is not a classification problem and each of them are meaningful. I expect to get a zero or one for each of them. Right now I have used the Euclidean loss function.

There are 1000000 samples. In the input file, each of them have 144 features, so there the size of the input is 1000000*144.
I have used batch size of 50, because otherwise the processing time is too much.
The output file is of the size 1000000*4, i.e. there are four output per each input.

When I am using the accuracy layer, it complains about the dimension of output. It needs just one Boolean output, not four. I think it is because it considers the problem as a classification problem. 
I have two questions.
First, considering the error of the accuracy layer, is the Euclidean loss function suitable for this task? And How I can get the accuracy for my network?
Second,I gonna get the exact value of the predicted output for each of the four variable. I mean I need the exact predicted values for each test record. Now, I just have the loss value for each batch. 
Please guide me to solve those issues.

Thanks,
Afshin

The train network is:

```
{ state {
 phase: TRAIN
}
 layer {
   name: "abbas"
   type: "HDF5Data"
   top: "data"
   top: "label"
   hdf5_data_param {
     source: "/home/afo214/Research/hdf5/simulation/Train-1000-11-     1/Train-Sc-B-1000-11-1.txt"
     batch_size: 50
   } 
 }

 layer {
   name: "ip1"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   bottom: "data"
   top: "ip1"
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 350
     weight_filler {
       type: "xavier"
     }
   }
 }

 layer {
   name: "sig1"
   bottom: "ip1"
   top: "sig1"
   type: "Sigmoid"
 }

 layer {
   name: "ip2"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   bottom: "sig1"
   top: "ip2"
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 150
     weight_filler {
       type: "xavier"
     }
   }
 }
```

The test network is also:

```
       state {
       phase: TEST
       }
        layer {
        name: "abbas"
        type: "HDF5Data"
        top: "data"
        top: "label"
        hdf5_data_param {
         source: "/home/afo214/Research/hdf5/simulation/Train-1000-11-         1/Train-Sc-B-1000-11-1.txt"
          batch_size: 50
         }
        }

        layer {
         name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "ip1"
  inner_product_param {
  num_output: 350
  weight_filler {
   type: "xavier"
  }
 }
 }

  layer {
  name: "sig1"
  bottom: "ip1"
   top: "sig1"
   type: "Sigmoid"
 }


   layer {
     name: "ip2"
     type: "InnerProduct"
     bottom: "sig1"
     top: "ip2"
     inner_product_param {
       num_output: 150
       weight_filler {
         type: "xavier"
       }
     }
   }


   layer {
     name: "sig2"
     bottom: "ip2"
     top: "sig2"
     type: "Sigmoid"
   }


   layer {
     name: "ip4"
     type: "InnerProduct"
     bottom: "sig2"
     top: "ip4"
     inner_product_param {
       num_output: 4
       weight_filler {
         type: "xavier"
       }
     }
   }
   layer {
     name: "accuracy"
       type: "Accuracy"
         bottom: "ip4"
          bottom: "label"
             top: "accuracy"
             }


   layer {
     name: "loss"
     type: "EuclideanLoss"
     bottom: "ip4"
     bottom: "label"
     top: "loss"
   }
```

And I get this error:

> ```
> accuracy_layer.cpp:34] Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ ==  bottom[1]->count() (50 vs. 200) Number of labels must match number of   predictions; e.g., if label axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H,   W), label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, with integer values in   {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
> ```

Without using the accuracy layer caffe gives me the loss value.

Comment: can you post the prediction, loss and accuracy layers you are currently using?

Comment: @Shai
I added my training layer here.

Comment: I am more interested at the top layers: the prediction, loss and accuracy layers. BTW what is the `shape` of your input `"label"`?

Comment: @Shai
The input label is a table with size of N*200, however the predicted labels are of size N*50. Note that 50 is my batch size, and for each batch I have 4 output, however caffe gives just one prediction.

Comment: you are very unclear. please post your prototxt and explain what is `N` and why you have batch-size dimension mixed up with label dimension (instead of N*50*4 you have N*200)??

Comment: @Shai
sorry for that.

Comment: no.problem, but please edit your question to make it clearer

Comment: @Shai
I have added some more details.
Also, the .prototxt is added in the question. please let me know if you nedd more details.

Comment: please post the entire prototxt

Comment: @Shai
There is similar one for test.

Comment: what about the loss and accuracy layers?

Comment: @Shai
I posted the test network also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Should `"EuclideanLoss"` be used for predicting binary outputs?

If you are trying to predict *discrete* binary labels then `"EuclideanLoss"` is not a very good choice. This loss is better  suited for regression tasks where you wish to predict continuous values (e.g., estimating coordinated of bounding boxes etc.).
For predicting discrete labels, `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` or [`"InfogainLoss"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30497907/1714410) are better suited. Usually, `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` is used.
For predicting binary outputs you may also consider [`"SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142623/1714410).

#### Why is there an error in the `"Accuracy"` layer?

In [caffe](/questions/tagged/caffe), "`Accuracy"` layers expects two inputs ("bottom"s): one is a prediction *vector* and the other is the ground truth expected *discrete* label.
In your case, you need to provide, *for each binary output* a vector of length 2 with the predicted probabilities of 0 and 1, and a single binary label:

```
layer {
  name: "acc01"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "predict01"
  bottom: "label01"
  top: "acc01"
}
```

In this example you measure the accuracy for a *single* binary output. The input `"predict01"` is a two-vector for each example in the batch (for `batch_size: 50` the shape of this blob should be 50-by-2).

#### What can you do?

You are trying to predict 4 *different* outputs in a single net, therefore, you need **4** *different* loss and accuracy layers.
First, you need to split (`"Slice"`) the ground truth labels into 4 scalars (instead of a single binary 4-vector):

```
layer {
  name: "label_split"
  bottom: "label" # name of input 4-vector
  top: "label01"
  top: "label02"
  top: "label03"
  top: "label04"
  type: "Slice"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 1
    slice_point: 2
    slice_point: 3
  }
}
```

Now you have to have a prediction, loss and accuracy layer for each of the binary labels

```
layer {
  name: "predict01"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "sig2"
  top: "predict01"
  inner_product_param {
    num_outout: 2 # because you need to predict 2 probabilities one for False, one for True
    ...
}
layer {
  name: "loss01"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "predict01"
  bottom: "label01"
  top: "loss01"
}
layer {
  name: "acc01"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "predict01"
  bottom: "label01"
  top: "acc01"
}
```

Now you need to replicate these three layer for each of the four binary labels you wish to predict.