# How to train a caffemodel on our own dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I tried using pre-trained *bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel* for object recognition from images. I got good results for images containing only a single object. For images with multiple objects, I removed the `argmax()` term from prediction which gives the class label with the maximum probability.

Still, the accuracy is very less for the labels which I am getting. So, I am thinking of training the same *caffemodel* on my own dataset (containing images with multiple objects). How should I proceed? Is there any way to retrain a pre-trained *caffemodel* with the different dataset?

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to train your network for single label or multi-label classification. For multi-label classification use PR #523 of Caffe.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is called "finetuning": taking a deep net trained for task A, reusing its weights and re-train it to accomplish task B.
You can start with [this tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html), but you will find much more information simply by googling "finetune caffe model".

You may also be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142623/1714410) regarding training caffe with mutiple categories per input image.

Comment: How much time does a pretrained caffemodel take for finetuning, if I am about to use CPU instead of GPU?

Comment: depends on number of iterations you run

Comment: I am using a very less dataset for training just for now. How many iterations should I go with?

Comment: @foo how many iterations does it take to cover the new training set once (an "epoch")?

Comment: my solver.prototxt file is like:
`
net: "/home/foo/Project/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "/home/foo/caffe/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/caffenet_train"
solver_mode: CPU
`