# Caffe sigmoid cross entropy loss

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am using the sigmoid cross entropy loss function for a multilabel classification problem as laid out by [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pascal-multilabel-with-datalayer.ipynb). However, in both their results on the tutorial and my results, the output predictions are in the range `(-Inf, Inf)`, while the range of a sigmoid is `[0, 1]`. Is the sigmoid only processed in the backprop? That is, shouldn't a forward pass squash the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example the input to the `"SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"` layer is the output of a fully-connect layer. Indeed there are no constraints on the values of the outputs of an `"InnerProduct"` layer and they can be in range `[-inf, inf]`.
However, if you examine carefully the `"SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"` you'll notice that it includes a [`"Sigmoid"` layer inside](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.hpp#L99) -- to ensure stable gradient estimation.
Therefore, at test time, you should replace the `"SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"` with a simple `"Sigmoid"` layer to output per-class predictions.

Comment: Thank you @Shai. You are clutch with these Caffe answers