# Cross-entropy implementation in Caffe

Tags: c++, neural-network, caffe, cross-entropy

Looking at the source code in sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cpp, which is the source code for Cross-Entropy loss function in caffe, I noticed that the code for the actual error value is

```
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    loss -= input_data[i] * (target[i] - (input_data[i] >= 0)) -
        log(1 + exp(input_data[i] - 2 * input_data[i] * (input_data[i] >= 0)));
  }
```

which seems to be rather different from the CE loss function in the documentation for Caffe or C++ implementation I found here:

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2014/04/01/Neural-Network-Cross-Entropy-Error.aspx?Page=2

or in fact the definition of CE loss function.

Is this some sort of approximation? I first thought it is Taylor series expansion of log⁡(1−x), but it doesn't work like that at all.

Answer (score 1):

the loss implemented by this layer is not *just* cross entropy. The layer implements Sigmoid activation followed by cross entropy loss. This allows for a more numerically stable implementation of the loss.

see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36538327/1714410) for more information.
Also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41800604/1714410).

Comment: ah ok then: I plugged in phat = 1/(1+exp(-x)) in the CE equation, and I'm only getting the result for x_n<0: -input_data[i]*target[i] + log(1+exp(input_data[i])) after x_n[i] cancels out.  I don't see a problem with log (negative number) anywhere. How did you get the  input_data[i] >= 0?

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry. I can't understand your comment. Can you please edit your question?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think SO supports mathjax, so the formula is hard to read.  I'm referring to lines 95 and 96 in sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cpp, and variable input_data[i] >= 0. How did you get it?