# How to use SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss in caffe for binary class classification?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, matcaffe

How to use SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss in caffe for binary class problem?
Can you give me a prototxt example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your `label` input to be either zero or one per training sample. other than that

```
 layer {
   name: "loss"
   type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
   bottom: "predict1d"
   bottom: "label"
   top: "loss"
 }
```

Comment: I tried the same way. Before this layer I had a layer with number of output is equals to 1. I also tried "SoftmaxWithLoss". It seems "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss" is very much slower than "SoftmaxWithLoss". Do you have any idea about why this happens?

Comment: @user570593 unfortunately I have no experience with this loss layer