# Caffe classification labels in HDF5

Tags: neural-network, classification, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am finetuning a network. In a specific case I want to use it for regression, which works. In another case, I want to use it for classification.

For both cases I have an HDF5 file, with a label. With regression, this is just a 1-by-1 numpy array that contains a float. I thought I could use the same label for classification, after changing my EuclideanLoss layer to SoftmaxLoss. However, then I get a negative loss as so:

```
    Iteration 19200, loss = -118232
    Train net output #0: loss = 39.3188 (* 1 = 39.3188 loss)
```

Can you explain if, and so what, goes wrong? I do see that the training loss is about 40 (which is still terrible), but does the network still train? The negative loss just keeps on getting more negative.

**UPDATE**
After reading [Shai's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020322/caffe-classification-labels-in-hdf5?noredirect=1#comment69261015_41020322) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41027539/1714410), I have made the following changes:
 - I made the `num_output` of my last fully connected layer 6, as I have 6 labels (used to be 1).
 - I now create a one-hot vector and pass that as a label into my HDF5 dataset as follows

```
    f['label'] = numpy.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Trying to run my network now returns

> ```
>    Check failed: hdf_blobs_[i]->shape(0) == num (6 vs. 1)
> ```

After some research online, I reshaped the vector to a 1x6 vector. This lead to the following error:

> ```
>   Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (40 vs. 240) 
>    Number of labels must match number of predictions; e.g., if softmax axis == 1 
>    and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), label count (number of labels) 
>    must be N*H*W, with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
> ```

My idea is to add 1 label per data set (image) and in my train.prototxt I create batches. Shouldn't this create the correct batch size?

Comment: what is the `num_output` of the layer before the SoftmaxWithLoss layer?

Comment: @Shai num_output was 1 when I made this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you moved from regression to classification, you need to output not a scalar to compare with `"label"` but rather a probability *vector* of length num-labels to compare with the discrete class `"label"`. You need to change `num_output` parameter of the layer before `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` from `1` to num-labels.

I believe currently you are accessing un-initialized memory and I would expect caffe to crash sooner or later in this case.

**Update**:
You made two changes: `num_output` 1-->6, and you also changed your input `label` from a scalar to vector.
The first change was the only one you needed for using `"SoftmaxWithLossLayer"`.
Do not change `label` from a scalar to a "hot-vector".

Why?
Because `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` basically looks at the 6-vector prediction you output, interpret the ground-truth `label` as **index** and looks at `-log(p[label])`: the closer `p[label]` is to 1 (i.e., you predicted high probability for the expected class) the lower the loss. Making a prediction `p[label]` close to zero (i.e., you incorrectly predicted low probability for the expected class) then the loss grows fast.

---

Using a "hot-vector" as ground-truth input `label`, may give rise to multi-category classification (does not seems like the task you are trying to solve here). You may find [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112941/1714410) relevant to that particular case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Strangely enough, caffe didn't crash. I updated my question with how I understood your suggestions and the results!

Comment: Thank you! My program behaves more like I expected! My Iteration loss is still negative, however. Any ideas what causes this?

Comment: @user4039874 using `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` should never result with negative values. something fishy is going on. (1) are you sure you have no other loss layers in your model? (2) are you sure all `label` values in HDF5 are *integers* with values `{0,1,2,3,4,5}` only? is it possible you have some examples with `label==6`?

Comment: Silly of me. My labels didn't start at 0. I changed that and now the model is training. Thanks again!

Comment: @user4039874 now the question is why didn't you get a segmentation fault? is it possible your caffe is compiled with debug flags?

Comment: That is very much possible. My caffe runs on a server and I had to try several configurations to get it to install and make it usable.

Comment: @user4039874 in that case you might not get optimal performance (in term of run time and mem usage) from your caffe...

Comment: For this case, that is not a problem. But I will definitely keep track of it in the future!

Comment: Hi Shai, I have same problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280783/video-classification-using-hdf5-in-caffe. Could you look at it?