# Video classification using HDF5 in CAFFE?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I am using hdf5 layer for video classification (C3D). This is my code to generate hdf5 file

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import skvideo.datasets
import skvideo.io

videodata = skvideo.io.vread('./v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c01.avi')
videodata=videodata.transpose(3,0,1,2) # To chanelxdepthxhxw
videodata=videodata[None,:,:,:]

with h5py.File('./data.h5','w') as f:
    f['data'] = videodata
    f['label'] = 1
```

Now, the `data.h5` is saved in the file `video.list`. I perform the classification based on the prototxt

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./video.list"
    batch_size: 1
    shuffle: true
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1a"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1a"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "msra"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: -0.1
    }
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc8"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "conv1a"
  top: "fc8"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 101
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

However, I got the error as

```
I0918 22:29:37.163431 32197 hdf5.cpp:35] Datatype class: H5T_INTEGER
F0918 22:29:37.164500 32197 blob.hpp:122] Check failed: axis_index < num_axes() (1 vs. 1) axis 1 out of range for 1-D Blob with shape 6 (6)
```

Update: When I change the code as `f['label'] = 1`, I also got the error `F0918 23:04:39.884270  2138 hdf5.cpp:21] Check failed: ndims >= min_dim (0 vs. 1)`
How should I fix it? I guess the hdf5 generating part has some error in label field. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

1. Please read **carefully** the answer you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020322/caffe-classification-labels-in-hdf5?noredirect=1&lq=1):
   Your `label` should be an integer and **not** a 1-hot vector.
2. It seems like your `data` is of type integer. I suppose you would like to convert it to `np.float32`. And while you are at it, consider subtracting the mean.
3. Since your HDF5 file has only one sample, you cannot have `label` as a scalar ("0 dim array"). You need to make `label` as `np.ones((1,1), dtype=np.float32)`.
   Use `h5ls ./data.h5` to verify that `label` is indeed an array and not a scalar.

Comment: Thanks, Shai. Of course, i check label as `label=1` before and I got the error `Check failed: ndims >= min_dim (0 vs. 1) `. Let see my update question

Comment: You are right. It worked now. Thanks so much. What is happen if I have 6 labels. For example, video 1->label 1, video2->label 2 and so on