# Caffe Image Data Layer with multiple labels

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am currently trying to build a CNN that takes in images. The label that I want is the (i,j) coordinates. I know that the image data layer that uses a file with the filename and the label in the following format:

folder/file1.jpg label

Is it possible to have a label that isn't a number but two numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680860/caffe-with-multi-label-images

Comment: To some extent. I am still not sure if the format with the txt file and ImageData works. I am away from my usual computers so I can't really test it.