# Create LMDB for image dataset with k-hot labels

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I wanna to create a classifier for an image dataset that each image is in multiple classes from all classes, so the target values are k-hot vectors. Now I create a text file which contains address if image file and space and a k-hot  vector in each line but when i try to run scripts to create lmdb files it raise errors that can not open or find files. I try the same process with same data and just a number as class label and everything goes well. So I think it cannot parse .txt file correctly when labels are vectors.

Any suggestion...
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Caffe [`"Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/data.html) layers and [`convert_imageset`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31427094/1714410) script were written with a very specific use case in mind: image classification. Therefore the basic element stored in (and fetched from) LMDB by caffe is [`Datum`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L30-L41) that has a room for a [*single* *integer* label](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L36).
<sub>You can see a more lengthy discussion on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410)</sub>

It does not mean Caffe cannot facilitate different types of inputs/tasks.
You can use [`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer instead. When it comes to hdf5 inputs caffe has almost no restrictions on the input shape and size.
See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32687772/1714410) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) for more details on how to actually make it work.

Comment: @Thank you, yes finally I can convert image dataset to HDF5 format