# Generating LMDB for Caffe

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I am trying to build a deep learning model for Saliency analysis using caffe (I am using the python wrapper). But I am unable to understand how to generate the lmdb data structure for this purpose. I have gone through the Imagenet and mnist examples and I understand that I should generate labels in the format

```
my_test_dir/picture-foo.jpg 0
```

But in my case, I will be labeling each pixel with 0 or 1 indicating whether that pixel is salient or not. That won't be a single label for an image.

How to generate lmdb files for a per pixel based labeling ?

Comment: the current interface of `caffe` and `lmdb` supports only a single label per image (suitable for classification tasks). However, you can use HDF5 interface. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can approach this problem in two ways:

**1.** Using HDF5 data layer instead of LMDB. HDF5 is more flexible and can support labels the size of the image. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) for an example of constructing and using HDF5 input data layer.

**2.** You can have two LMDB input layers: one for the image and one for the label. Note that when you build the LMDB you must **not** use the `'shuffle'` option in order to have the images and their labels in sync.

**Update:** I recently gave a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181897/1714410).

Comment: That's really helpful. HDF5 method is quite clear. However, out of curiosity, how do I go about adding two layers following the second method ? I am not able to understand that!

Comment: @Unni it should be quite easy: create two lmdb `train_images_lmdb' and `train_labels_lmdb` then you add two input layers one with top "image" and "dummy_label_1", the other with top "label_image" and "summy_label_2".

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. Pretty helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this one: http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/

Just load all images in `X` and corresponding labels in `Y`.

Comment: This is not even relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In caffe both lmdb and hdf5 supports multiple labels per image, matrices if you like, see this thread:

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1698#issue-53768814

See this tutorial on how to create a multi-label dataset (lmdb here) for caffe with python code:

http://www.kostyaev.me/article/Multilabel%20Dataset/

EDIT: For example for the labels it uses the caffe-python function which converts a 3-dimensional array to datum, found in caffe/python/caffe.io.py:
array_to_datum(arr, label=None):

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.

Comment: Second link is dead, do you have another link to provide ? thanks.

Comment: The link was down for a while, it was not in the web archive but I now found it is back up again. And is now in the web archive. Thanks