# How to create LMDB files for semantic segmentation?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I have downloaded [PASCAL trainval.tar.gz and 33_context_labels](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/~roozbeh/pascal-context/) and saved into two folders for running semantic segmentation. The **trainval** folder includes images with **.mat** format and ground truth images in **33_context_labels** folder are in **.png** format.

- How can I divide the training data (trainval folder) and corresponding label images (33_context_labels folder)  into 2 sets: One for training (5/6 of images) and the other for validation (1/6 of images)?
- How can I create LMDB files for the training and validation in 2 LMDB databases? (train_lmdb for training the model and validation_lmbd for model evaluation)

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why lmdb and not HDF5?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33628970/1714410) for more details.

Comment: you are most welcome.

Comment: @Shai Thanks a lot, but how we can create this file for each pixel for semantic segmentation. How it works? Could you please explain?

Comment: you do not build a file per pixel, but rather a "label image" per input image. That is, instead of a scalar label per input image, you now have a label image with a label per input pixel.

Comment: @Shai thank you very much, but how we can relate label images to the corresponding original images? should I create one database for labels and another one for original images?

Comment: you should be very careful when constructing the two lmdb to make sure they are in sync. please see [this linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627888/generating-lmdb-for-caffe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Shai Thank you very much for your help and support. I am beginner in Caffe and Python, and I asked a lot of questions. You are the only person that reply most of the time and very quickly. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: glad I could help. I believe [tag:python] questions will get answers from more users... [tag:caffe] is a bit lonely ;)

Comment: @Shai, I think your contributions are worth writing up as an answer.

Comment: @Shai unfortunately, I am not able to convert to LMDB. Each image is in mat file format and labels are in another folder with mat file format. I have one channel images (grayscale). What solution do you suggest? thanks

Comment: @S.EBif you have access to matlab (mat format is native to matlab) then read the files in matlab and convert them to hdf5

Comment: @Shai My apologies for bothering you, in the [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774953/test-labels-for-regression-caffe-float-not-allowed/31808324#31808324) , what is `'train.txt'` file that is opening? I do not have such file for my data.

Comment: @S.EB the same input file as in convert_imageset: each line has a path to an image file and the corresponding ground truth label of that image

Comment: @Shai   since I am quite new in Caffe, how can I create such text file. I have many thousands images. Should I do it manually, or is there any script that is doing that? Thanks in advance