# Modifying Caffe to accept 16 bit data inside lmdb

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I'm trying to make some modifications on Caffe in order to accept my 16 bit data.
I succeded into creating a lmdb dataset filled with 16 bit unsigned, unencoded 256x256 image instead of usual caffe 8 bit unsigned data, saved as "string" as would be the usual 8 bit lmdb that can be created with `image_convert` or DIGITS utilities.
I've changed the `io.py` functions `array_to_datum` and `datum_to_array` in order to create this lmdb at 16bit "string" data.
Now, if I use this lmdb on caffe (just 4 classes), the networks runs but doesn't converge. I strongly suspect that is not reading my data properly.
Problem is, the `io.py` functions `array_to_blobproto` and `blobproto_to_array` doesn't seems to make any distinction between internal data contents, and I cannot find the code where I should modify for dealing with 16bits.
Could anyone give me an hint to where to work on?

Edit: 
Messing around in the code, I think that one of the possibility should be to create a new data layer or a new image data layer if I would like to work directly on the png without going throught lmdb. But trying to modify that C++ code is not a trivial task for me, esp. I cannot easily follow the data flow inside the code. I see that new layer can be written in python. Do you  think that a new input data layer could work nicely or would slow down the cnn performance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about converting and adapting caffe/lmdb interface, but it seems like a very risky path to take if you are not 100% certain with what you are doing.
For instance, you changed the io functions in the python interface, but I don't think caffe is using this interface when running from command line (e.g., `$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/caffe train ...`). Have you looked into the cpp io functions in [`io.cpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/util/io.cpp) file?

I would strongly suggest an alternative path: use hdf5 binary inputs instead of lmdb.
You can convert the 16bit images you have to float32 and store them in hdf5 files, then input them to caffe via `"HDF5Data"` layer.

Read more about hdf5 and caffe [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410).