# How to save an image in levelDB

Tags: c++, kinect, caffe, leveldb

I started a new project in deep learning with caffe. I need to get lots of RGB/Depth/infrared images and some other information from kinect 4 windows and analyze them with caffe. 
Caffe uses leveldb/lmdb for large scale data import/export. leveldb is installed on my c++ project and its wotking correctly.
Now, what is the most efficient way to save images on leveldb? is it enough to convert image to a byte array and put in in leveldb?

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37265977/1714410) might inspire you

Comment: By saying 'the most efficient way', what do you mean? It is ok to store image to levelDB, but it depends on the kind of performance you care about, the throughout of write or the latency of read.