# caffe - float multi-label LMDB file

Tags: python, c++, caffe

I want to feed caffe vectors of float multi-labels. I created an `image_list.txt` which contains path of images and float labels in each line, e.g.

```
/path/image.jpg  4.4732 6.9842 17.4382
```

is it possible to create  `LMDB` file with float multi-labels data? (I'm not using MatLab). thanks.

Comment: no. caffe lmdb interface only supports Datum type which stores a single int label per image. use HDF5Data layer instead

Comment: Here is a solution for `LMDB` http://stackoverflow.com/a/37291510/6281477

Comment: @Dale this links give a solution for 1 float label. I want to feed caffe vectors of float multi-labels. thanks

Comment: @Shai do you have a solution for HDF5Data with include vectors of float multi-labels? thank you

Comment: @Z.Kal I do. please search for other caffe multi label answers

Comment: @Z.Kal please check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410)