# Single Float label , LMDB Format in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I am using caffe for a regression problem and I want to know how is possible to use [lmdb](/questions/tagged/lmdb) format for single float label.

Right now, caffe only supports `int32` type label for lmdb data (type of `label` in [`Datum`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L30-L41) is `int32`).
In order to change this default behavior, I changed some of files in caffe as follows but the problem has stayed and after converting my labels all are zero.

```
caffe.proto -> line36 : int32 to float
convert_imageset.cpp -> line 75 and 77 : int to float
io.cpp and io.hpp -> all the labels were int , I changed them to float
```

After all I compiled caffe again but it doesn't work.

Is there anyone to solve this problem. it is very important to me to solve it as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, you can also choose to save the `label` in the field `float_data` of `Datum`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31774953/6281477 this post may also helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist to force caffe to support float labels, you might need to change [`convert_imageset.cpp` line 81](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/convert_imageset.cpp#L81) as well.
Currently this line uses [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) to convert string to **int**:

```
label = atoi(line.substr(pos + 1).c_str());
```

You should convert it to user [`atof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) to convert string to **float**:

```
label = atof(line.substr(pos + 1).c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Only this line, not those i mentioned in the question ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it and inform you

Answer (score 1):

Solving your problem by forcing and tweaking caffe to work with float labels in LMDB dataset seems like not a very good strategy.

I suggest instead to use caffe's `"HDF5Data"` layer. Using hdf5 format to store data for caffe is much more flexible and allows you to have float labels.

For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410).

Comment: thanks , to use "HDF5Data" as the current version has limit size and we need to split data, it means, we have to convert every piece(to satisfy the limit size) of data separately?