# caffe: A CNN with two loss layers and two different label sets

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am interested to have a deep CNN with two loss layers, each of them having its own separate label set. For example, imagine a 10 layer CNN, loss1 is located in 5th layer using label1, then loss2 in the last layer using label2.

Note: label1 (loss1) can be considered as pre-processing step, in order to ease the task of the CNN to solve label2 (loss2 i.e. real label).
[image]

**Question:** as far as i know, caffe loss layer automatically uses "label" (in my .lmdb dataset). how to make it to use "label1" in loss1 and "label2" in the loss2?

**Update:** so i took Shai's advice to use HDF5. here is my progress so far (giving only the input and output layers):

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label1"
  top: "label2"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "data/2048_1e3_0.00/2048_1e3_0.00_s_val_list.txt"
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label1"
  top: "label2"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "data/2048_1e3_0.00/2048_1e3_0.00_s_train_list.txt"
  }

...

layer {
  name: "loss1"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "ampl"
  bottom: "label1"
  top: "loss1"
}

...

layer {
  name: "loss2"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "ampl"
  bottom: "label2"
  top: "loss2"
}
```

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: thanks Shai. the "this answer" link you provided is not addressing the question about using multiple loss using multiple labels. so i decided to make my question more clear by "update".

also, I provided a part of code, to ask if that is how I should do it or not. what is wrong with that?

Comment: The answer I [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) shows how to create HDF5 data for caffe. You should modify it have multiple labels instead of just `X` and `Y`. And yes, the direction you took seems to lead to a good solution.

Comment: i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Caffe stores binary [`Datum`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L30-L41)s in lmdb. The way `Datum` is defined restricts it to a **single** integer [label](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L36) per input image. Therefore it can be very tricky to use [`"Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/data.html) layer with lmdb in your scenario.

On the other hand you can use [`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer instead: this layer is much more flexible and can easily provide with more than a single label per input image. There are several examples here at SO on how to use this input layer, see, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410).