# Caffe - multi-class and multi-label image classification

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to create a single multi-class and multi-label net configuration in caffe.

Let's say classification of dogs:
Is the dog small or large? (class)
What color is it? (class)
is it have a collar? (label)

Is this thing possible using caffe?
What is the proper way to do so?
What is the right way to build the lmdb file?

All the publications about multi-label classification are from around 2015, something in this subject changed since then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Caffe's LMDB interface is that it only allows for a [single int label per image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410).
If you want multiple labels per image you'll have to use a different input layer.
I suggest using [`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer:
This allows for more flexibility setting the input data, you may have as many `"top"`s as you want for this layer. You may have multiple labels per input image and have multiple losses for your net to train on.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) on how to create hdf5 data for caffe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52912707/1714410),

Just trying to understand the practical way.. 
After creating 2 .text files (one for training and one for validation) containing all the tags of the images, for example:

```
/train/img/1.png 0 4 18
/train/img/2.png 1 7 17 33
/train/img/3.png 0 4 17
```

Running the py script:

```
import h5py, os
import caffe
import numpy as np

SIZE = 227 # fixed size to all images
with open( 'train.txt', 'r' ) as T :
    lines = T.readlines()
# If you do not have enough memory split data into
# multiple batches and generate multiple separate h5 files
X = np.zeros( (len(lines), 3, SIZE, SIZE), dtype='f4' ) 
y = np.zeros( (len(lines),1), dtype='f4' )
for i,l in enumerate(lines):
    sp = l.split(' ')
    img = caffe.io.load_image( sp[0] )
    img = caffe.io.resize( img, (SIZE, SIZE, 3) ) # resize to fixed size
    # you may apply other input transformations here...
    # Note that the transformation should take img from size-by-size-by-3 and transpose it to 3-by-size-by-size
    # for example
    transposed_img = img.transpose((2,0,1))[::-1,:,:] # RGB->BGR
    X[i] = transposed_img
    y[i] = float(sp[1])
with h5py.File('train.h5','w') as H:
    H.create_dataset( 'X', data=X ) # note the name X given to the dataset!
    H.create_dataset( 'y', data=y ) # note the name y given to the dataset!
with open('train_h5_list.txt','w') as L:
    L.write( 'train.h5' ) # list all h5 files you are going to use
```

And creating train.h5 and val.h5 (is X data set containing the images and Y contain the labels?).

Replace my network input layers from:

```
layers { 
 name: "data" 
 type: DATA 
 top:  "data" 
 top:  "label" 
 data_param { 
   source: "/home/gal/digits/digits/jobs/20181010-191058-21ab/train_db" 
   backend: LMDB 
   batch_size: 64 
 } 
 transform_param { 
    crop_size: 227 
    mean_file: "/home/gal/digits/digits/jobs/20181010-191058-21ab/mean.binaryproto" 
    mirror: true 
  } 
  include: { phase: TRAIN } 
} 
layers { 
 name: "data" 
 type: DATA 
 top:  "data" 
 top:  "label" 
 data_param { 
   source: "/home/gal/digits/digits/jobs/20181010-191058-21ab/val_db"  
   backend: LMDB 
   batch_size: 64
 } 
 transform_param { 
    crop_size: 227 
    mean_file: "/home/gal/digits/digits/jobs/20181010-191058-21ab/mean.binaryproto" 
    mirror: true 
  } 
  include: { phase: TEST } 
}
```

to

```
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "X" # same name as given in create_dataset!
  top: "y"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "train_h5_list.txt" # do not give the h5 files directly, but the list.
    batch_size: 32
  }
  include { phase:TRAIN }
}

layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "X" # same name as given in create_dataset!
  top: "y"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "val_h5_list.txt" # do not give the h5 files directly, but the list.
    batch_size: 32
  }
  include { phase:TEST }
}
```

I guess HDF5 doesn't need a mean.binaryproto?

Next, how the output layer should change in order to output multiple label probabilities?
I guess I need cross- entropy layer instead of softmax?
This is the current output layers:

```
layers {
  bottom: "prob"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  name: "loss"
  type: SOFTMAX_LOSS
  loss_weight: 1
}
layers {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: ACCURACY
  bottom: "prob"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include: { phase: TEST }
}
```

Comment: is this an answer? or is it another question?

Comment: you do not need `mea.binaryproto` in your prototxt, but if you want to subtrat mean (and you do) you need to do it when you create the hdf5 files.

Comment: you only save one of the labels in your text files (the first one) and ignore all the rest.

Comment: It's a follow-up question since i'm still trying to understand your original answer.
I didn't understand your last answer, i'm trying to classify multilabel network, hence each image have several labels related. What do you mean by "ignore all the rest"?

Comment: then posting it as an answer is not exactly a good idea: I have no way of knowing that you posted it, nor do I understand what you are asking here. If you have questions, post them as such (you can link one question to the other for context).

Comment: I opened up a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53047003/multi-class-and-multi-label-image-classification-using-caffe