# Caffe MLP example

Tags: machine-learning, caffe

I'm trying to learn caffe by making an xor example.

I'm following this [link](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html) from the caffe website, but they are doing a CNN.

I'm trying to follow along the tutorial and I am stuck when it comes to compiling the model.

I made a `prototxt` file describes the model architecture, I am trying to make a two layered xor network. My code is below:

```
name: "xor_test"

layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  transform_param {
    scale: 1
  }
  data_param {
    source: "0 0 0
             1 0 1
             0 1 1
             1 1 0"

    backend: LMDB
    batch_size: 1
  }
  top: "data"
  top: "data"
}

layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  param { lr_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
  bottom: "data"
  top: "ip1"
}

layer {
  name: "tanh1"
  type: "Tanh"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip1"
}

layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  param { lr_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
}

layer {
  name: "tanh2"
  type: "Tanh"
  bottom: "ip2"
  top: "ip2"
}
```

I don't know if this model is correct, I can't find other examples to reference.

After this, the tutorial says to create a solver `prototxt` file which referenced the previously created file.

```
net: "test.prototxt"
test_iter: 2
test_interval: 5
base_lr: 0.01
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
lr_policy: "inv"
gamma: 0.0001
power: 0.75
display: 5
# The maximum number of iterations
max_iter: 10
# solver mode: CPU or GPU
solver_mode: CPU
```

I'm not sure how to train or test the model since my inputs are not images.

Answer (score 0):

Your input layer is incorrect. Since you are not using images as inputs, but rather simple binary vectors, you might consider using [`HDF5Data`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer for input.
There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) on how to construct and use this input data layer.