# HDF5 Input to caffe

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe, hdf5, pycaffe

I am trying to follow [this example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/brewing-logreg.ipynb) posted on git.
I want to modify the example and use  data I have downloaded(wisconsin breast cancer dataset). I have it all transferred from csv to hdf5 file.
It is not clear to me how am I suppose to input this data to the network?
It consists of 700 rows and 11 columns which 1 of the columns is the 'label' column for prediction.
To my understanding each row should be inputed independently to other rows for correct training?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) on how to prepare HDF5 data for caffe's [`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) input layer.

Basically, you need to have two "datasets" inside the hdf5 file: one for the inputs and one for the label. Each dataset is a multi-dimensional array with the first dimension being the "batch" dimension. In your example, you have 700 examples of dimension 10 as input and 700 labels of dimension 1.