# How to convert non image data to lmdb format for caffe

Tags: python, input, caffe, lmdb

I have data where the input is of size [1,1,625] ( width and height is 1 and number of channels is 625). The input size cannot be changed since I need to use the weights of a pretrained model which was trained using this  as the input size. I am new to caffe and hence am not able to convert this data into lmdb format for caffe training. Each cell of input can either be 0 or 1 and the target values for the meantime can be considered to be 1 for all the inputs. 
Also how to do it if the input is of size [1,1,2] and both the values in the output can be float.

I am trying to run this [code](https://github.com/CSAILVision/GazeCapture/tree/master/models) on my own dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can force your data into lmdb format, but I'm afraid this can be quite messy. [This](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1698#issuecomment-70211045) github snippet shows how you can use python to write custom lmdb data for caffe.

However, I think that in your case, where you have floating point labels in mind, a better strategy would be to use [hdf5](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) file format for the inputs. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) shows how this can be done.