# How to training/testing my own dataset in caffe?

Tags: matlab, dataset, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I started with Caffe and the mnist example ran well.
I have the train and label data as `data.mat`. (I have 300 training data with 30 features and labels are `(-1, +1)` that have saved in `data.mat`).

However, I don't quite understand how I can use caffe to implement my own dataset?

Is there a step by step tutorial can teach me?

Many thanks!!!! Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most straight forward way to transfer data from Matlab to caffe is via HDF5 file.

First, save your data in Matlab in an HDF5 file using [`hdf5write`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5write.html). I assume your training data is stored in a variable name `X` of size 300-by-30 and the labels are stored in `y` a 300-by-1 vector:

```
hdf5write('my_data.h5', '/X', 
  single( permute(reshape(X,[300, 30, 1, 1]),[4:-1:1]) ) );
hdf5write('my_data.h5', '/label', 
  single( permute(reshape(y,[300, 1, 1, 1]),[4:-1:1]) ), 
  'WriteMode', 'append' );
```

Note that the data is saved as a 4D array: the first dimension is the number of features, second one is the feature's dimension and the last two are 1 (representing no spatial dimensions). Also note that the names given to the data in the HDF5 are `"X"` and `"label"` - these names should be used as the `"top"` blobs of the input data layer.

Why `permute`? please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431532/1714410) for an explanation.

You also need to prepare a text file listing the names of all hdf5 files you are using (in your case, only `my_data.h5`). File `/path/to/list/file.txt` should have a single line

> /path/to/my_data.h5

Now you can add an input data layer to your train_val.prototxt

```
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  top: "X"     # note: same name as in HDF5
  top: "label" # 
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/list/file.txt"
    batch_size: 20
  }
  include { phase: TRAIN }
}
```

For more information regarding hdf5 input layer, you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31634295/1714410).

Comment: Did you manage to run training of a net on MATLAB using Caffe?

Comment: @Drazick sorry but I do not mix Matlab and caffe. The Python interface is much better

Comment: I saw you answered a lot of troubled MATLAB users hence I thought you have some experience. It really seems the MATLAB interface is buggy. I have something working on Command Line yet crashes MATLAB.

Comment: @Drazick I used to work extensively with Matlab, but nowadays I am more of a Python coder...

Comment: Do you have any experience with Caffe on MATLAB? Thank You.

Comment: @Drazick sorry, no. But I strongly recommend you make the effort to use the Python interface

Comment: Well, the problem is they don't support Python 3.5 on Windows.