# Single Label Regression(Finetuning) With Input Artificial Features In Caffe

Tags: matlab, neural-network, regression, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have,say, `n` images and for each of them I have additional 2 artificial(made-up) features, and image-labels are single dimensional integers.

I want to fine-tune Image-net on my dataset, but I do not know how to handle these 2 additional features as input, how should I feed the data to caffe? Please help!

EDIT: The 2 features can be any 2 numbers (1 dimensional) say two numbers representing what class an image falls into, and how many images fall into that class.

Say, I have 'cat.jpg', then the features are say, 5 and 2000, where 5 is the feature 1 representing the class and 2000 is the total images in that class. 
In short, the 2 features can be any two integers.

Comment: @Shai Please, can you help me?

Comment: Are your two features the 4096 dim ones? your question is unclear.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question to make my question clearer. The 4096 thing was just an example for better understanding of my question.

Comment: @Shai, I have made the edit, do you understand my question now? Thanks for the response, by the way!

Comment: so you have n images as input and two n by 1 additional inputs for training?

Comment: @Shai yes, that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straight forward way for you is to use `"HDF5Data"` input layer, where you can store both the input images, the additional two "features" and the expected output value (for regression).

You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) for creating HDF5 data in python. A Matlab example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34261942/1714410).

Your HDF5 should have 4 "datasets": one is the input images (or the image descriptors of dim 4096). `n` dimensional array of images/descriptors.
Another dataset is `"feat_1"` an `n` by 1 array, and `"feat_2"` and `n` by 1 array.
Finally you should have another input `"target"` an `n` by 1 array of the expected output you wish to learn.

Once you have an HDF5 file ready with these datasets in it, you should have

```
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data" # name of dataset with images/imagenet features
  top: "feat_1"
  top: "feat_2"
  top: "target"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/list/file.txt"
  }
}
```

As you can see a *single* `"HDF5Data"` layer can produce several "top"s.

Comment: I read somewhere that I would have to use the Concatenation Layer, isn't that the case?

Comment: @Deven Yes, if you want to feed imagenet feature, feat_1 and feat_2 to the same InnerProduct layer, you will need to use Concatanation layer.

Comment: I am a bit out of my depth here, I do not know whether I should feed them to the same InnerProduct layer or not. Please explain.

Comment: @Deven I can't make this call for you. Eventually, in order to produce a single output you should merge all your inputs into a single classification/regression layer (usually an InnerProduct layer). However, you might want to pass your inputs through one or more hidden layers before you make your prediction, though...

Comment: To give you some more info, I am just modifying the flickr style finetuning example, and making small modifications(like Euclidean loss for regression). What I will be doing now is modifying the data layer(as told by you) and just adding a concatenation layer(before the IP layer), would I be doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99616/discussion-between-deven-and-shai).

Comment: From the matlab example you linked, I have understood that if X is a n dimensional array of images, then I would use: hdf5write('my_data.h5', '/X', single( permute(X,[4:-1:1]) ) ) Am I right in doing so?

Comment: @Deven yes. you can use the command line util `h5ls` to make sure that the shape of your inputs is correct