# Creating large LMDBs for Caffe with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I have two 60 x 80921 matrices, one filled with data, one with reference.
I would like to store the values as key/value pairs in two different LMDBs, one for training (say I'll slice around the 60000 column mark) and one for testing. Here is my idea; does it work?

```
X_train = X[:,:60000]
Y_train = Y[:,:60000]
X_test = X[:,60000:]
Y_test = Y[:,60000:]

X_train = X_train.astype(int)
X_test = X_test.astype(int)
Y_train = Y_train.astype(int)
Y_test = Y_test.astype(int)

map_size = X_train.nbytes * 10
env = lmdb.open('sensormatrix_train_lmdb', map_size=map_size)
with env.begin(write=True) as txn:  
    for i in range(60):
        for j in range(60000):
            datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
            datum.height = X_train.shape[0]
            datum.width = X_train.shape[1]
            datum.data = X_train[i,j].tobytes()
            datum.label= int(Y[i,j])
            str_id= '{:08}'.format(i)
```

I'm really not sure of the code. And what does the last line `format(i)` refer to?

Comment: why don't you use `"HDF5Data"` input layers? you have `h5py` package to store numpy arrays as hdf5 data files. See an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34261942/1714410) (the example uses matlab to write the data, but it is even simpler in python using `h5py`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do: are you treating each entry as a separate data sample, or are you trying to train on 60K 1D vectors of dim=60...

Assuming you have 60K training samples of dim 60, you can write the training lmdbs like this:

```
env_x = lmdb.open('sensormatrix_train_x_lmdb', map_size=map_size) # you can put map_size a little bigger 
env_y = lmdb.open('sensormatrix_train_y_lmdb', map_size=map_size)
with env_x.begin(write=True) as txn_x, env_y.begin(write=True) as txn_y:
    for i in xrange(X_train.shape[1]):
        x = X_train[:,i]
        y = Y_train[:,i] 

        datum_x = caffe.io.array_to_datum(arr=x.reshape((60,1,1)),label=i)
        datum_y = caffe.io.array_to_datum(arr=y.reshape((60,1,1)),label=i)
        keystr = '{:0>10d}'.format(i) # format an lmdb key for this entry
        txn_x.put( keystr, datum_x.SerializeToString() ) # actual write to lmdb
        txn_y.put( keystr, datum_y.SerializeToString() )
```

Now you have two lmdb for training, in your `'prototxt'` you should have two corresponding `"Data"` layers:

```
layer {
  name: "input_x"
  top: "x"
  top: "idx_x"
  type: "Data"
  data_param { source: "sensormatrix_train_x_lmdb" batch_size: 32 }
  include { phase: TRAIN }
}
layer {
  name: "input_y"
  top: "y"
  top: "idx_y"
  type: "Data"
  data_param { source: "sensormatrix_train_y_lmdb" batch_size: 32 }
  include { phase: TRAIN }
}
```

To make sure you read corresponding `x` `y` pairs, you can add a sanity check

```
layer {
  name: "sanity"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "idx_x"
  bottom: "idx_y"
  top: "sanity"
  loss_weight: 0 
  propagate_down: false
  propagate_down: false
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you said, like 60% of it. Okay, I am indeed trying to train 60k vectors (and then using the remaining 21k vectors for 'testing'... Now um, I'm very confused about the details of what you said. (this is my first conv net using caffe, woohoo! Let me work out exactly how to phrase my questions and I'll get back to you. Thanks so much. But I suppose the main question is- how exactly are we getting our X vectors to match up with our Y vectors?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull please look into `"HDF5Data"` - I think it will suit you better in this case.

Comment: Thanks Shai, I will do.

Comment: Also, could you explain this error? 
---> 12         env_x.put( keystr, datum_x.SerializeToString() ) # actual 
AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'put'

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull my bad. please see the corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks Shia. One more question- if I'm implementing softmax regression at the end, what does the layer definition look like? I'm assuming I need to define 2 layers?

Comment: Shia I'm not sure I understand your answer. I'm trying to train the X vectors to match the Ys... with two LMDBs how do I do this?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull as I wrote in the answer you'll have two `'Data'` layers in your model: one for `x` and one for `y`. The `"sanity"` layer makes sure that at each iteration the corresponding `x` and `y` are used.