# create hfd5 with float numbers for caffe

Tags: neural-network, regression, deep-learning, caffe, multilabel-classification

I want to feed caffe vectors of labels (multi label regression problem), so I have used the [following link](https://github.com/nikogamulin/caffe-utils) for creating hdf5 files.
Using this code, I created an `image_list.txt` which contains path of files and float labels in each line, e.g.

> ```
> /home/deep/00000.bmp  0.9997 0.0236 -0.0082 -0.0231 0.9980 0.0588 0.0096 -0.0586 0.9982 -0.0046 0.1084 0.3938
> ```

but it seems that it only works for integer label.
when I run `demo.m` the following error comes:

> Error using `dataread`
>       Trouble reading integer from file (row 1, field 3) ==> .9997 0.0236      -0.0082 -0.0231 0.9980
>   0.0588 0.

Comment: have you considered [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34261942/1714410)?

Comment: @Shai the link you mentioned is about integer labeles not float.

Comment: the link I sent is on how to create hdf5 data from MATLAB to be used by caffe

Answer (score 0):

If you also use caffe's C++ interface, I would like to share you with this [Multitask DataLayer](https://github.com/DaleSong89/caffe-mt) and it supports float typed label vector for regression tasks. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37291510/6281477) provides a simple example for learning facial expressions' label distribution which is a vector size of 8.