# How do I go about having a cross-entropy layer in Caffe?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am working on a CNN where the last layer is supposed to be a cross-entropy layer where I compare 2 images. I am imposed to use Caffe. I checked on layer catalogue. And there isn't a cross-entropy layer, only a Sigmoid cross-entropy. I asked my supervisor who told that using wouldn't do.

So here is my question. Is vanilla cross-entropy hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no [vanilla cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) in caffe till now. There are only some special instances of cross-entropy in caffe, for example, SigmoidCrossEntropyLossLayer and MultinomialLogisticLossLayer.

**But you can get vanilla cross-entropy by simply modefiying the
MultinomialLogisticLossLayer**. Because this layer computes cross-entropy assuming that the target probability distribution is a form of one-hot vector, so by modifying its computation formula by assumming the target probability distribution a general probability distribution you can get the vanilla cross-entropy. Hope that will help you.

**Orignal MultinomialLogisticLossLayer in caffe:**

```
template <typename Dtype>
void MultinomialLogisticLossLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(
        const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom, const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
   const Dtype* bottom_data = bottom[0]->cpu_data();
   const Dtype* bottom_label = bottom[1]->cpu_data();
   int num = bottom[0]->num();
   int dim = bottom[0]->count() / bottom[0]->num();
   Dtype loss = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
      int label = static_cast<int>(bottom_label[i]);
      Dtype prob = std::max(bottom_data[i * dim + label], Dtype(kLOG_THRESHOLD));
      loss -= log(prob);
   }
   top[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[0] = loss / num;
}
```

**Assume that bottom[1] contains target/true distribution, then Cross EntropyLossLayer should be like this now:**

```
void CrossEntropyLossLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(
         const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom, const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
    const Dtype* bottom_data = bottom[0]->cpu_data();
    const Dtype* bottom_label = bottom[1]->cpu_data();
    int num = bottom[0]->num();
    int dim = bottom[0]->count() / bottom[0]->num();
    Dtype loss = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j){
            Dtype prob = std::max(bottom_data[i * dim + j], Dtype(kLOG_THRESHOLD));
            loss -= bottom_label[i * dim + j] * log(prob);
        }
    }
    top[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[0] = loss / num;
}
```

**Similarly, the corresponding backward_cpu function for back propagation will be:**

```
template <typename Dtype>
void CrossEntropyLossLayer<Dtype>::Backward_cpu(
const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top, const vector<bool>& propagate_down,
        const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom) {
    if (propagate_down[1]) {
        LOG(FATAL) << this->type()
            << " Layer cannot backpropagate to label inputs.";
    }
    if (propagate_down[0]) {
        const Dtype* bottom_data = bottom[0]->cpu_data();
        const Dtype* bottom_label = bottom[1]->cpu_data();
        Dtype* bottom_diff = bottom[0]->mutable_cpu_diff();
        int num = bottom[0]->num();
        int dim = bottom[0]->count() / bottom[0]->num();
        caffe_set(bottom[0]->count(), Dtype(0), bottom_diff);
        const Dtype scale = -top[0]->cpu_diff()[0] / num;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j){
                Dtype prob = std::max(bottom_data[i * dim + j], Dtype(kLOG_THRESHOLD));
                bottom_diff[i * dim + j] = scale * bottom_label[i * dim + j] / prob;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also read that SoftmaxWithLoss is actually softmax+MultinomialLogisticLossLayer. Is there a way to use SoftmaxWithLoss to do softmax+CE?

Comment: @AlperenAYDIN yes, SoftmaxWithLoss is softmax+MultinomialLogisticLoss, so the solution of softmax+CE is to modify the MultinomialLogisticLoss computation part of the SoftmaxWithLossLayer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have been a great help. Now there is the problem of how to modify MultinomialLogisticLoss

Comment: And the problem of how to support label of float typed vector  in caffe, for this problem you will come across,  you can follow this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697671/create-hfd5-with-float-numbers-for-caffe/37701220#37701220 @AlperenAYDIN

Comment: Actually, I import images using two Data layers from 2 databases. So that isn't really a problem as long as softmaxwithloss accepts matrices.

Comment: @AlperenAYDIN The modification of MultnominalLogistcLoss for vanilla cross entropy has been updated in my answer, hope it will help you.