# Making hdf5 data with 2d mat file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, caffe, hdf5

I am trying to do binary classfication in caffe. I have 900 training samples and each sample is a 30-by-15 .mat file and `label` is a 900-by-1 .mat file(+1,-1). 
Now, my question is how can I make hdf5 data to feed the caffe network. I know how to do it with 1d sample data([this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249025/how-to-training-testing-my-own-dataset-in-caffe)) .

kindly someone help me out.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the same, only your`X` now has `size`: `[900 30 15 1]`