# Create hdf5 file with combination of image and matrix

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I tried to retrain a model from [this github](https://github.com/senguptaumd/SfSNet/tree/master/SfSNet_train) but I encounter a problem of creating hdf5 for it. So far i only know that hdf5 should contain images path and possible label/class of it. 
But on my case, it has a combination of images and matrix of light estimation. Is this possible to achieve or did I make wrong interpretation of the instruction. Please help me understand this

This is one of the light estimation matrix that they provide

```
0.300794    0.121209    -0.115402   0.073493    -0.126265   -0.035606   0.013735    -0.018538   -0.055469   0.202293    0.105253    -0.058834   0.047335    -0.097811   -0.032969   0.010878    -0.024713   -0.028035   0.150027    0.096441    -0.049527   0.032507    -0.088273   -0.033228   0.007316    -0.015788   -0.021543
```

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34261942/1714410) on how to create hdf5 data for caffe

Comment: it doesn't answer my question. I don't have label but instead I have matrix

Comment: your matrix is the label

Comment: I see, So should I encode it like this whole matrix should be 1 and next group of matrix should be 2 or just put it in as it is?