# Use hdf5 as caffe input, error: HDF5Data does not transform data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I used hdf5 file as caffe input data, and the error occured:

> ```
> hdf5_data_layer.cpp:75] Check failed: !this->layer_param_.has_transform_param() HDF5Data does not transform data.
> ```

This is my defination:

```
layer {
  name: "weight28"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  include { phase : TRAIN } 
  transform_param { scale: 0.00392156862745098 }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/home/zhangyu/codes/unsupervised/data/weight28.h5"
    batch_size: 8
  }
  top: "weight28"
}
```

Here is some  information of my h5 file:

```
HDF5 weight28.h5 
Group '/' 
    Dataset 'data' 
        Size:  2555000x28
        MaxSize:  Infx28
        Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
        ChunkSize:  28x28
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0.000000
```

I find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31634295/1714410) and the answer said  *You cannot use transform param in the hdf5data layer.* 
What dose data transform in caffe do? Can I just cancel it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As you already spotted yourself, you cannot have `transformation_param` in a `"HDF5Data"` layer - caffe does not support this.
2. As for the transformation parameters themselves, look at [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L408-L429):

> ```
> // For data pre-processing, we can do simple scaling and subtracting the
> // data mean, if provided. Note that the mean subtraction is always carried
> // out before scaling.
> optional float scale = 1 [default = 1];
> ```

Having `transform_param { scale: 0.00392156862745098 }` means your net expects your input to be scaled by `0.0039..` (1/254).
You can (and probably should) scale the data by 1/254 when you create the hdf5 data files for training and then remove the `transform_param` from the `"HDF5Data"` layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I removed the transform parameter and solved that. But it came with this error again: `Check failed: H5LTfind_dataset(file_id, dataset_name_) Failed to find HDF5 dataset`. Is there something wrong with my preparing of the hdf5 file? I was intended to prepare a dataset of 91250x28x28 which was feeded to the net together with other data defined in leveldb. @Shai

Comment: @user6931072 sounds like a new question to me. from the error message it seems like caffe cannot find the files.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the error mentioned by user6931072 `Check failed: H5LTfind_dataset(file_id, dataset_name_) Failed to find HDF5 dataset`:

You should provide a text file as the source, not an hdf5 file. So, instead of `source: "/home/zhangyu/codes/unsupervised/data/weight28.h5"`, make a text file that lists the hdf5 file and then use `source: "/home/zhangyu/codes/unsupervised/data/myhdf5data.txt"`.